# Constraint column value based on another column? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

i am trying to set my defaults column Y or N based on membershipType column.
There can be only one Y in defaults column based on the 3 different value in membershipType column. Other than that, others will be N. How do i do it?

```
ID  titlePromo   membershipType         defaults
--  ----------   --------------         ------
1    Promo 1     Membership Promotion      Y
2    Promo 2     Membership Renewal        Y
3    Promo 3     Membership Grad           Y
4    Promo 4     Membership Promotion      N
5    Promo 5     Membership Promotion      N
6    Promo 6     Membership Grad           N
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a unique filtered index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uixDefault 
ON dbo.Promotions(membershipType)
WHERE defaults = 'Y';
```

This stops there being a second row with `defaults='Y'` of the same membershipType.

Comment: an error occur : The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.Promotions' and the index name 'uixDefault'. The duplicate key value is (Membership Promotion                                                                                ).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: my table name is dbo.Promotions

Comment: Do you have multiple rows with "Membership Promotion", that have Y?

Comment: oh my fault, there are duplicates of y in same promotion type. It works thanks!

Comment: No worries. Happy to help. :)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again, is there anyway that once i insert a Y another row in default column instead of showing error, the column that used to have the value Y be able to change to N and the new row will have the value Y?

Comment: Then really you want a different table design. You should have a table which lists the membership types (one row per membership type), with a value to indicate the default promotion.

Comment: But with your current design, you could use a trigger on INSERT and UPDATE which does: `UPDATE dbo.Promotions SET defaults = 'N' WHERE defaults = 'N' and membershipType IN (SELECT membershipType FROM Inserted);`

Comment: Sorry but the inserted is? is is okay if you give an example? i am quite new to this. Sorry

Comment: `Inserted` is the way that you refer to the new set of rows that will remain after the insert/update. The code you should use is: `CREATE TRIGGER trgDefaults ON dbo.Promotions AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS BEGIN; UPDATE dbo.Promotions SET defaults = 'N' WHERE defaults = 'Y' AND membershipType IN (SELECT membershipType FROM Inserted); END`